# How to send array and boolean data in body of POST request of API

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, request, fetch-api

How I can send array and boolean data in the body of POST request of API.
Following is the code through which I was trying to send the array and boolean data but it gets converted into the string.

```
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://35.153.16.107:8080/restaurant/createProfile',{
        method:'post',
        headers:{Authorization:localStorage.getItem('token'), 'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            route:this.state.route,
            side:this.state.side,
            mustHaveDishes:this.state.mustTryDishes,      //This is array
            preOrderDineIn:this.state.preOrderDineIn,     //This is boolean
            preOrderTakeaway:this.state.preOrderTakeaway, // This is boolean
            veg:this.state.vegOnly                        // This is boolean 
        }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{
        if(data.statusCode === '2000'){
            console.log(this.state.mobile);
            this.props.onRouteChange('orderar','nav');
        }
        else
         console.log(data.error);
    })
```

This is how I want to send the array and boolean data-

```
        mustHaveDishes:["paratha"],
        preOrderDineIn:true,
        preOrderTakeaway:true,
        veg:true
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you think is `JSON.stringify` doing other than taking a JSON object and transforming it into a string?

Body should look like

```
body: {
  route: this.state.route,
  side: this.state.side,
  mustHaveDishes: this.state.mustTryDishes,
  preOrderDineIn: this.state.preOrderDineIn,
  preOrderTakeaway: this.state.preOrderTakeaway,
  veg: this.state.vegOnly
},
```

Comment: But then how I will transform route and side to string?

Comment: What are `route` and `side` and why should they be transformed to string?

Comment: route will contain two city name {exp- route: "NewYork-LA"} which will be entered by the user and side is the name of a single city {exp- side:"NewYork"}

Comment: Actually the format of sending data to the API is- 
`route:"New York- LA",
side:"New York",
mustHaveDishes:["paratha"],
 preOrderDineIn: true,
  preOrderTakeaway: true,
  veg: true`

Comment: So if route and side are strings already why would you want to stringify them a second time?

Comment: No they are not string. I have shown the format in which I want to pass the data. Can I convert them into string by any other method?

Comment: Yes, for example using `JSON.stringify`. But if you stringify the whole request you shouldn't be surprised that the whole request is stringified.